# MS-SQL Server security document

Tags: untagged

I have to build sql- server security architecture doc based on our existing PROD server, what all it takes to build a doc from scratch. Is there any good website for the template for the doc?

Comment: Maybe start here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/solutions-technologies/mission-critical-operations/security-and-compliance.aspx. I think the MS Curriculum is training classes so I don't think you're going to find that online in elec. format.

Answer (score 3):

> I have to build sql- server security architecture doc based on our existing PROD server

Already you are *Doing It Wrong* -- define your security requirements, document an architecture that meets, them, then perform a gap analysis and show what must be done to make your production environment meet the security requirements.
[Greg Askew already aimed you at some Microsoft documentation which will help](https://serverfault.com/a/470389/32986).

---

I'm going to be brutally honest - If you need to come to Server Fault asking `what all it takes to build a doc from scratch` (and you're not just asking about *formatting*) *you are not qualified to take on this task*.  Security is something that takes experience, and you may want to consider getting a professional DBA with security experience to help you draft your security policy and ensure your system conforms to it.

Answer (score 1):

**SQL Server Security Best Practices - Operational and Administrative Tasks**
http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/F/A/8FABACD7-803E-40FC-ADF8-355E7D218F4C/SQL_Server_2012_Security_Best_Practice_Whitepaper_Apr2012.docx

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/solutions-technologies/mission-critical-operations/security-and-compliance.aspx